# Trim last 4 characters from worksheet vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having problem trying to apply this codes to worksheet..
can anyone provide some guidance?
basically I have my filenames converted as worksheet and I want to remove .pdf from it..
`Left(Sh.Name, Len(Sh.Name)-4)` 
I also have problem `dim Sh.Name as String` so I have no idea how to proceed from here to apply the above..

```
Sub findstring()

 Dim sh As Worksheet, myCounter
 Dim Loc As Range, str As Variant

sh.Name = Left(sh.Name, Len(sh.Name) - 4)


For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

 If sh.Name <> "email" Then 
 With sh.UsedRange
 Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:="Truck")

 If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox sh.Name

            myCounter = 1
            Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)

 End If

End With
End If Next
If myCounter = 0 Then
MsgBox "Value not present in this workbook"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Show your code till now

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
sh.Name = Left(sh.Name, Len(sh.Name) - 4)
```

... `sh` is just declared, not defined. If you want to do this to all the worksheets of your workbook, you can remove this line of code and use the loop just below:

```
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Right(sh.Name,4) = ".pdf" Then
        sh.Name = Left(sh.Name, Len(sh.Name) - 4)
    End If
Next sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `.pdf` from any string with

```
x = replace(x, ".pdf", "")
```

You can remove any filename from a string with

```
x = Left(x, InStrRev(x, ".") - 1)
```

Danger being that the string might contain a "." but not actually a file extension.

Comment: question.. I'm getting an error to dim sh.name as a string so how do I go about doing it if I want to choose option 3 by using Instr?

Comment: Actually with your code you need to just put `sh.Name = Left(sh.Name, Len(sh.Name) - 4)` AFTER the `For each sh in thisworkbook.sheets` your problem is that you're trying to rename a sheet that you have not defined yet