# VBA Excel - save file name with partially changed name

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I would like to save the workbook under the partially changed string.

The name of my current file is:

**DPP_EDI-1-PN66-SN8_28 Lochend Drive_EH7 6DJ_V1.0**

and the full name remains the same. I just only want to change by end of the string from V1.0 to V2.0 or higher (based on the cell value).

I found some solution here:
[Trim last 4 characters from worksheet vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50316780/trim-last-4-characters-from-worksheet-vba)

and tried the following code:

```
  Sub Version_save()
  Dim wbn As ThisWorkbook
  If Right(wbn.Name, 4) = "V1.0" Then
  wbn.Name = Left(wbn.Name, Len(wbn.Name) - 4)
  End If

  End Sub
```

I am getting the error:
**I can't assign to a read-only property.**

How can I save the new file with these small changes in my string?

Comment: `Dim wbn As ThisWorkbook` is problematic too.

Comment: You need to `SaveAs` to actually change the name.

Comment: I have got the Save As code prepared. I am just wondering how to keep the same string with the very end changed.

Comment: Then your question is no longer about assigning to a read-only property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you need to do is to "drop" the file extension from the end of the file name, and then remove the existing version number (in your current case "V1.0") and replace it with the new version from the worksheet (in my example I've used "V4.0" in cell "A1" of "Sheet1"), and then reattach the file extension:

```
Sub sChangeVersion()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim strFileName  As String
    Dim strFileExt As String
    strFileName = ThisWorkbook.Name
    strFileExt = Mid(strFileName, InStrRev(strFileName, "."))
    strFileName = Left(strFileName, InStrRev(strFileName, ".") - 1) '   get rid of the file extension (it should be .xlsm)
    strFileName = Left(strFileName, InStrRev(strFileName, "V"))  '   now go back to the last "V" in the file name
    strFileName = strFileName & Format(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), "#0.0") & strFileExt
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFileName
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sChangeVersiojn", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

I've modified the code to add just the number (formatted as "x.x") from the worksheet.

Regards,

Comment: The code is working, but what I also need:
- save it in the same directory (or at least the popup Save-as window)
- I have the string ending "2" instead of "V2.0". Could you tell me in which line can I prepare the end of the string? 
My suggestion is:
strFileName = strFileName & "_V" &  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") & ".0" & strFileExt
something like this. Am I right?

Comment: Basically you can ignore my 2 point. Just tell my why my file is saved in my previous directory instead of the current one?

Comment: I've added code to use `ThisWorkbook.Path` to use the current path.

Answer (score 0):

Messy but it works. Basically get the string of the old name and
use Replace() to find piece of old string and swap with new value

```
Sub test()
Dim newVersion As String
newVersion = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text
Dim wbn As String
wbn = ThisWorkbook.Name
MsgBox (wbn)
Dim wbn2 As String
wbn2 = Replace(wbn, "V1.0", newVersion)
MsgBox (wbn2)
End Sub
```